# Cassandra Set Type

Tags: cassandra, set, cql

I have changed the field type from list to set and I receive the following error:

Error in creating model in method Cassandra\ActiveRecordBundle\Session\CassandraSession::getModelOriginal exception: 
Instantiation of a Cassandra\Type\Set type is not supported.

Can you please help with a hint or anything?

Tx

Comment: Include driver (language), version of cassandra, how you changed the field (alter table? changed object and rely on ORM?). I assume this is a rails error?

Comment: i've created a new database and the then i've updated the model in my symfony3 app

Comment: i use datastax php driver, cassandra version 3.0.4

Comment: should be there (http://datastax.github.io/php-driver/api/Cassandra/Type/class.Set/), perhaps update your php driver to latest. Also I would recommend upgrading C* as well, 3.0.4 isnt a very stable version.